# "Unique case violation" warning at time 0

Tags: system-verilog

I have a unique case statement inside an FSM that looks something like this:

```
enum logic [1:0] {IDLE = 2'b01,
                  RUN = 2'b10} state, next_state;
always_comb begin
  next_state=state;
  unique case(state)
    IDLE: next_state = RUN;
    RUN: next_state = IDLE
  endcase
end

always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rstb) begin
  if(!rstb) state <= IDLE;
  else state <= next_state;
end
```

I am getting a "Unique case violation" warning at time 0, presumably because everything starts up as `X`.  I am fairly certain that the above code will always have one and only one true case, so I would like to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically turn on/off assertions, including `unique case`, `unique if`, etc. with the system task `$assertcontrol`. Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 20.12 *Assertion control system tasks*.

Note that `$assertcontrol` is new (added in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html)) and some simulators may not support it. There are other system tasks that can enable/disable assertions such as `$asserton`, `$assertoff` which been around since pre IEEE1800 (I see it mentioned in Accellera SystemVerilog 3.0), but I'm not sure if they include `unique case`

If your simulator already supports `$assertcontrol` then you can use something like the following code. I recommend having the file that contains this code compile before any file that uses `unique case` to reduce the risk of a race condition at time 0.

```
parameter ON=3, OFF=4;
parameter UNIQUE=32, UNIQUE0=64, PRIORITY=128;
initial begin
  // Turn OFF the violation reporting for unique case, unique0 case, priority case, unique if, etc.
  $assertcontrol( OFF , UNIQUE | UNIQUE0 | PRIORITY );

  // Wait some time
  @(negedge rstb) #1ns; // or whatever delay statement you want

  // Turn ON the violation reporting for unique case, unique0 case, priority case, unique if, etc.
  $assertcontrol( ON , UNIQUE | UNIQUE0 | PRIORITY );
end
```

Comment: So funny story: The version of my simulator I was using doesn't support `$assertcontrol`. I upgraded to the newest version and it supports it. However, it also doesn't suffer from the false warning at time 0, so I don't actually need to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to assign a value (e.g. `IDLE`) to `state` inside declaration:

```
enum logic [1:0] {IDLE = 2'b01,
                  RUN = 2'b10} state = IDLE, next_state;
```

Of course you can also add `default` action to your case.

You have to remember it's only a warning. If you reset (`~rstb`) your module at the beginning, nothing wrong will happen if you ignore it.

Comment: I know that I can ignore the warning, but I like to clean up what I can.  If I assign `state=IDLE` then I get an error since `state` has multiple drivers.

Comment: @nguthrie: what IDE are you using? It works [just fine](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/GaJ) for me.

Comment: Cadence Incisive.  Seems like a bug since I found this in section 10.5 of the spec: `The variable declaration assignment is a special case of procedural assignment as it assigns a value to a
variable. It allows an initial value to be placed in a variable in the same statement that declares the variable`.  Of course, doing this assignment would mask a real problem where there is no reset for some reason.  What I really want is a way to suppress the warning at time 0.  That is probably tool specific.

Comment: You can use `ncelab -svperf -up` to disable `unique case` warnings. I'm not sure if you can disable warnings only at time 0.